# I keep getting this Window pop up saying localhost:4200 says undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongoose, restify

*AM trying to register using my angular as my frontend and nodejs,mongoose and restify as my backend the problem am getting is first the window pop up telling me that localhost:4200 says undefined then on my console i get this error this pop u window of localhost says undefined here is my code*

*Here is my api*

```
//Register clearadmin
        server.post('/register', (req, res, next) => {


         const email = req.body.email;
         const password = req.body.password;

         const clearadmin = new Clearadmin({
             email,
             password
         });

         bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {


            bcrypt.hash(clearadmin.password, salt, async (err, hash) => {

                //Hash Password
                clearadmin.password = hash;


                //save clearadmin
                try{
                   const newClearadmin =  await clearadmin.save()
                   res.send(newClearadmin).json({
                       success:true,
                       message:'registration succesful'
                   })
                   next();

                }
                catch(err)
                {
                    res.send(500).json({success:false,message:'Failed to Register'});
                 return next(new errors.InternalError(err.message));
                }
            });
         });
        });
```

*Here is my login component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { AuthService } from 'src/app/auth.service';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-login',
      templateUrl: './login.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

      constructor(private Auth: AuthService,private router: Router) { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }
      loginUser(event)
      {
        event.preventDefault()
        const target = event.target
        const email= target.querySelector('#email').value
        const password = target.querySelector('#password').value


        this.Auth.loginUser(email, password).subscribe(data => { 
          if(data.success)
          {
            //redirect the person to admin page
            this.router.navigate(['admindashboard'])
            this.Auth.setLoggedIn(true)


          }
          else
          {
            window.alert(data.message)
          }

        });
        console.log(email, password)
      }

    }
```

Comment: Without the code what you have tried its difficult to guide you.

Comment: Did you miss off half of your question? You said _"then on my console I get this"_ but never completed that thought.

Comment: the question is coming soon

Comment: there is my code fells help me guys am newbie in developing an apis